# arsenal::tableby and R Notebook: incorrectly added a row with NA

Tags: r, r-markdown, rnotebook

With the following code in a `R Notebook` file, I run `arsenal::tableby` from `tableby` help file. As shown in the screenshot, a row with `NA` has been added. I have tried both `R Markdown` and `script`, and they work fine. Is this a `R Notebook` issue or an `arsenal` issue, or that I have done something wrong?

---

````
---
title: "R Notebook"
output: html_notebook
---

```{r}
library(arsenal)
data(mockstudy)
tab1 <- tableby(arm ~ sex + age, data=mockstudy)
summary(tab1, text=TRUE)
````

[image]

Comment: Did you ever get this answered? Same problem here.